# Grouping words and more

Tags: clojure, transformation, keyword

I'm working on a project to learn Clojure in practice. I'm doing well, but sometimes I get stuck. This time I need to transform sequence of the form:

```
[":keyword0" "word0" "word1" ":keyword1" "word2" "word3"]
```

into:

```
[[:keyword0 "word0" "word1"] [:keyword1 "word2" "word3"]]
```

I'm trying for at least two hours, but I know not so many Clojure functions to compose something useful to solve the problem in functional manner.

I think that this transformation should include some partition, here is my attempt:

```
(partition-by (fn [x] (.startsWith x ":")) *1)
```

But the result looks like this:

```
((":keyword0") ("word1" "word2") (":keyword1") ("word3" "word4"))
```

Now I should group it again... I doubt that I'm doing right things here... Also, I need to convert strings (only those that begin with `:`) into keywords. I think this combination should work:

```
(keyword (subs ":keyword0" 1))
```

How to write a function which performs the transformation in most idiomatic way?

Comment: [the clojure cheatsheet](http://clojure.org/cheatsheet) is an excellent reference by the way

Comment: @noisesmith, indeed! I use [ClojureDocs](http://clojuredocs.org/) now, but one should know name of function to find info there. Thanks for you suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a high performance version, using `reduce`

```
(reduce (fn [acc next]
          (if (.startsWith next ":")
            (conj acc [(-> next (subs 1) keyword)])
            (conj (pop acc) (conj (peek acc)
                                  next))))
        [] data)
```

Alternatively, you could extend your code like this

```
(->> data
     (partition-by #(.startsWith % ":"))
     (partition 2)
     (map (fn [[[kw-str] strs]]
            (cons (-> kw-str
                      (subs 1)
                      keyword)
                  strs))))
```

Answer (score 1):

what about that:

```
(defn group-that [ arg ]
  (if (not-empty arg)
    (loop [list arg, acc [], result []]
      (if (not-empty list)
        (if (.startsWith (first list) ":")
          (if (not-empty acc)
            (recur (rest list) (vector (first list)) (conj result acc))
            (recur (rest list) (vector (first list)) result))
          (recur (rest list) (conj acc (first list)) result))
        (conj result acc)
        ))))
```

Just 1x iteration over the Seq and without any need of macros.

Comment: It must be really efficient because it looks eerily :-) (All efficient functions look bad.) Note that my code doesn't use macros too.

Comment: After remembering to add a doall to your version while benchmarking, @Mark, this one is twice as fast (as is Leon Grapenthin's cleaner reduce based version)

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is already here... This is my best effort:

```
(def data [":keyword0" "word0" "word1" ":keyword1" "word2" "word3"])

(->> data
     (partition-by (fn [x] (.startsWith x ":")))
     (partition 2)
     (map (fn [[[k] w]] (apply conj [(keyword (subs k 1))] w))))
```

I'm still looking for a better solution or criticism of this one.

Comment: I think `(apply conj [(keyword (subs k 1))] w)` is better than this use of backtick in terms of clarity.

Comment: `(apply conj [x] y)` is better written as `(into [x] y)`.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's construct a function that breaks vector `v` into sub-vectors, the breaks occurring everywhere property `pred` holds.

```
(defn breakv-by [pred v]
  (let [break-points (filter identity (map-indexed (fn [n x] (when (pred x) n)) v))
        starts (cons 0 break-points)
        finishes (concat break-points [(count v)])]
    (mapv (partial subvec v) starts finishes)))
```

For our case, given

```
(def data [":keyword0" "word0" "word1" ":keyword1" "word2" "word3"])
```

then

```
(breakv-by #(= (first %) \:) data)
```

produces

```
[[] [":keyword0" "word0" "word1"] [":keyword1" "word2" "word3"]]
```

Notice that the initial sub-vector is different:

- It has *no* element for which the predicate holds.
- It can be of length zero.

All the others

- start with their only element for which the predicate holds and
- are at least of length 1.

So `breakv-by` behaves properly with data that

- doesn't start with a breaking element or
- has a succession of breaking elements.

For the purposes of the question, we need to muck about with what `breakv-by` produces somewhat:

```
(let [pieces (breakv-by #(= (first %) \:) data)]
  (mapv
    #(update-in % [0] (fn [s] (keyword (subs s 1))))
    (rest pieces)))
;[[:keyword0 "word0" "word1"] [:keyword1 "word2" "word3"]]
```